# html doc opens a custom sized "url" window when executed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty much a beginner. I need help making a script in HTML format that when executed from an HTML doc opens a custom sized "url" window.

*IM NOT REFERRING TO A POP-UP THAT EXECUTES ITSELF FROM AN ALREADY OPENED PAGE.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `fancybox`:

http://fancybox.net/

You can set the url of the popup to be anything if you use it in `iframe` mode:

E.g.:

```
<a class="iframe" href="http://www.example">This goes to iframe</a>
```